# Geany does not auto-detect custom filetype upon opening

Tags: file-type, geany, file-type-associations

I've successfully created a new custom filetype using the Geany guide, however upon opening the file itself later I find I always have to manually set the filetype (Document > Set Filetype) instead of Geany auto-detecting it (the way it usually does with pre-configured filetypes like .md, .cs, etc).

Is there a reason for this? How can I get Geany to autodetect the filetype of a new custom filetype without having to manually set it everytime?

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Can you please add a link to the "Geany guide" to make it more clear for us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Same problem. Geany 1.38 on Ubuntu. I made filetype.avrc.conf in my ~/.config/geany/filedefs folder, based off filetype.c so I can have my particular avr-gcc build commands. I added lexer_filetype=C in the [settings] section and it works absolutely fine, except that when loading an avrc file Geany doesn't remember the filetype and has to be reminded. I've also tried putting an [extensions] entry in my user's filetype_extensions.conf, but it doesn't make any difference.